# iOS Push Notifications with Moon APNS - works on local, but not on server side

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications, ios7.1

So, we were using **Moon APNS** for **iOS** push notifications and everything worked fine until recent. Firstly, **Apple no longer supports ssl**, so we changed to TLS instead.

Second thing is (and this is a really strange one), that if we invoke **webservice** on **local computer** to send push notification, everything works fine. But, when we publish this code to our **testing server**, push notifications are **not delivered** to the phone, but the code is exactly the same!

One other thing, after `sendToApple` method is called, we get `OK status code`, just notification doesn't come.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the device you target the same, with the same build type ? If you switched from debug local build to adhoc deploy for the client for example, you need to push to production APNS and not sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting our solution, maybe someone has the same problem.

First of all, Moon APNS uses **SSL encryption**, but is deprecated by Apple. So you should alter Moon APNS library to use **TLS** instead. Second thing is, make sure you compile library with **Newtonsoft JSON library version 6.0.0.0**.

Our problem was, that we used older version of JSON library (I think the version was 4.x.x.x) and somewhere deep in the library exception occurred and returned 0 in sendToApple. Ironically, Apple uses `0` as `status OK`, so it was tricky to found out where the problem lies.

Comment: Which points out the need to always check results for errors.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't always possible, since we can't run debug on server for testing.

Comment: Had this exact issue, updated all projects to 6.0.0.0 and it worked. Had to modify my web.config as nuget didnt update that with the json update.